# Case-Insensitive String Filter

Tags: java, regex, string, filter, case-insensitive

This is a line of code I found :

`if(!word.matches("[a-zA-Z]{"+word.length()+"}")) return;`

Specifically what does `{"+word.length()+"}` do, what's the logic behind it, and where can I read more about it?

Comment: This makes sure to validate characters with a specific length, e.g. `[a-z]{4}` would satisfy `java`. You could as well have digits before and afterwards  though.

Comment: The code builds a string containing a regular expression. The regexp says that the target must contain (at least) `word.length()` consecutive letters.

Comment: shortcut for `!word.matches("[a-zA-Z]*")` from coder unfamiliar with `*` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces here mean that number of symbols, for example {4} means exactly four symbols. Here you specify entire string (inserting the length of it) to consist of small or large latin letters. Also you can specify {2-4} for example, meaning interval of number of letters that match given pattern. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading the parameters... this:

**"[a-zA-Z]{"+word.length()+"}"**

is the same as

```
    "[a-zA-Z]{" // this is a string

+

    word.length() // this is getting an integer( is the length of the string word)

+

    "}" //another litt. string.
```

so you are technically concatenating 2 strings and putting in the middle a number...

just that